# Aligning text to the center of an adjacent button on bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have the following jsfiddle modal

http://jsfiddle.net/WGGn6/1/

next to the sign in button I want to have a "forgot password" link.

problem is the link is not in the center of the button and it looks bad

[image]

the html code relevant is:

```
  <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls" style="position: relative;">
                    <div class="checkbox"><input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1"> <label for="user_remember_me">Remember me</label></div>
                <input class="control-group btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in"><a href="/users/password/new" data-remote="true" class="control-group" id="forgotpass" style="position: absolute; ">Forgot your password?</a>
```

which is created from the erb:

```
<div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls" style="position: relative;">
                <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
                    <div class="checkbox"><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
                <% end -%>
                <%= f.submit "Sign in" , :class => "control-group btn"%><%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' %><%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_user_password_path , :remote=>true, :style => "position: absolute; bottom: 0", :id=>"forgotpass" %>
                <% end -%>
                <%= ajaxloadericon %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What must be done for it to be in the center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with padding, which can move the text around.

```
​#forgotpass {
    padding: 5px 0 0 3px;
}​
```

will give you [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WGGn6/2/)